# Issue while taking backup of mysql database table using php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am Trying to get backup of mysql database table using php script below but by executing this script it is creating the backup file but with no data in it .Any idea how to overcome this please help me out. [image]

**Script**

```
<?php

echo exec('mysqldump -u[root] -p[123456789] -h[localhost] [Android] [houseDetails] --where="addedDate=\'2013-11-22 09:17:28\'"> houseDetails.sql');

?>
```

Comment: in the flag `--where` you specify that you only want fields that have the **exact** date to be `2013-11-22 09:17:28`. You might want to specify a date range or something like `addedDate >= "2013-11-22 00:00:00"` or `--where="addedDate BETWEEN '2013-11-22 00:00:00' and '2013-11-23 00:00:00'"`

Comment: And is your column name really `addedDate` or rather `added_date`?

Comment: still not getting records in file my column name is same that i had mention in my question.

Comment: please execute a select with the given where condition on your table and check if you get results........

Comment: If you do not get results in your select then you will not get results here also.

Comment: ya i am getting records when i run select query in phpmyadmin but not in backup file while executing the above question script

Comment: can you post your select query please

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `houseDetails`
WHERE `addedDate` = "2013-11-22 09:17:28"
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: still no luck how to get those records in backup file

Comment: are you sure, is it right? `--where="addedDate="2013-11-22 09:17:28""` i mean, 2 double quotes are there. try `--where="addedDate=\'2013-11-22 09:17:28\'"`

Comment: @lolka_bolka still no records please check my table records in snapshot that i recently posted

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("mysqldump -u root -ppassword db_name table_name --where=\"post_date in ('2011-12-15 06:14:55')\" > /tmp/test.sql");
```

Comment: still generating empty file

Comment: i am uploading database image so please check it

Comment: echo exec('mysqldump -u[root] -p[123456789] -h[localhost] [Android] [houseDetails] --where=" addedDate in ('2013-11-22 09:17:28')"> houseDetails.sql');

Comment: Try this: echo exec('mysqldump -u[root] -p[123456789] -h[localhost] [Android] [houseDetails] --where=" addedDate in ('2013-11-22')"> houseDetails.sql');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62806/discussion-between-ricky-and-vickrant).